# URLの「/?hoge=1」へアクセスした時だけ、「/」へリダイレクトするよう、.htaccessでURL操作したい

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing

**やりたいこと**
・URLの「?hoge=1」へアクセスした時だけ、「/」へリダイレクト
・上記以外はそのまま
・例えば、「?hoge=2」へアクセスした時などは、そのまま

**Q**
.htaccessで設定可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache HTTP Serverの [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) は .htaccess で使用できますね。(Contextの項を参照)

`RewriteRule` の前に [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) を置いて、特定の書き換えルールに対して条件を指定できます。このとき Query String の値は `%{QUERY_STRING}` で参照できます。