# 動的ページ（n）から静的ページ(1)に対しての301リダイレクト

Tags: .htaccess

サイトをリニューアルするにあたって、以前lightboxで大量に画像ページが存在していたURL群を静的ページに全てリダイレクトをかけたいと思っています。
lightboxのページが１万ページ近くあるのですが、n:nで画像が対応していないため、n:1で画像一覧ページにリダイレクトをかけようと思っています。

具体的には
?lightbox=
とつくURLは全て
/gallery/
というページにリダイレクトしたいのですが、.htaccessの記述方法がわかりません。。

初歩的な質問で大変恐縮なのですが、ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: これと同様の質問かな？ [URLの「/?hoge=1」へアクセスした時だけ、「/」へリダイレクトするよう、.htaccessでURL操作したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/url%E3%81%AE-hoge-1-%E3%81%B8%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91-%E3%81%B8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86-htaccess%E3%81%A7url%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84?rq=1)

Comment: 返信遅れてすみません！無事解決しました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: このような場所はただの回答を得るだけの場所でははなく「同様の問題を抱えた人が後で参考になる回答をストックする場所」でもあります。回答のデータベースを皆で作成しているというイメージです。できればどのように解決したのかを具体的に書いてもらうと(誰かが)助かります。

Comment: 失礼しました。下記のように解決しました。
----------------------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lightbox=
RewriteRule ^/gallery/? [R=301,L]
----------------------------------------------